# В каждом слове удалить последующие вхождения первой буквы этого слова

Tags: java

Помогите дописать код... Делать это все в обычном массиве, может быть?C `ArrayList` ничего не получается.

```
package lab3;

import java.util.*;

public class Strings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer("Slavas ochoen krasivyi malchik");
        String text1 = text.toString();
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String retlav : text1.split(" ")) {
            words.add(retlav);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            if(words.get(i).contains(words.get(i).get(0)) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "words.get(i).contains(words.get(i).get(0)" - тут как минимум не хватает закрывающейся скобки, почему вы пытаетесь вызвать метод get дважды подряд? И вообще, зачем вам проверка какого-то условия?

Comment: чтобы получить первую букву слова

Comment: но так не работает(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String [] text = "Slavas ochoen krasivyi malchik".split(" ");

    for(String s : text) {
        char distChar = s.charAt(0);
        sb.append(s.charAt(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i)!=distChar) sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Не вижу особого смысла в использовании коллекции типа лист, количество элементов которой заранее известно...

Answer (score 1):

Можно со стримами:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(text.toString().split(" "))
    .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1) + s.replaceAll(s.substring(0, 1), ""))
    .reduce((s, s2) -> s + " " + s2).get();
```

Comment: зачем `reduce`? может так `Stream.of(text.split(" ")).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).map(s -> s.charAt(0) + s.replaceAll("" + s.charAt(0), "")).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));` ?